# UITab Bar - Selection Indicator Image - Change Position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I am using a `UITabBarController`.  In my `AppDelgate` I am setting the `selectionIndicatorImage` to a simple white line.  This is showing up in the middle of the tab bar item.  I want it to show in the top of my tab bar item, highlighting that it is selected.  I tried making an image with a white line on top and transparent on the bottom but then it just showed up way above my tab bar.  Is there a certain size I need to make this image to achieve what I am after?

[image]

Image I'm Using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zva77z9yt6rcfsg/SelectedTab.png?dl=0

```
 UIImage *selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedTab"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:selectedImage]
```

Comment: what you need , you need line after selected tabbar

Comment: I added a picture to my question of what I am after.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ok minutes i will check for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `translucent` selectedTab (see zip file) with top white line and `height` should be `48 Pixel`

check this link  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j38mqj8sd0qgv8f/selectedTab.zip?dl=0

```
  [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedTab.png"]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

**Results:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple like image sizing.  Much appreciated my friend!

Comment: Any ideas how to remove the 1-2px gap on top of the tab bar above the selected image?  I tried making the image 2px taller but that messed everything up.